# Windows linking to libxml2.lib file, but cant find external symbols

Tags: c++, dll, linker, linker-errors, libxml2

I have built `libxml2.dll` with the latest 2.9.14 source. I was successful in creating the `.dll` and `.lib` files. I have linked the `.lib` file to my project, but when it comes to compile time, it doesn't seem to be able to resolve any of the libxml function calls I make in my program. It seems like the `.lib` file is incomplete.

I have gotten this to work in the past with an older version of libxml (2.9.3), that included a `libxml2.dll.a` file. No such file exists in the latest version, only a `.lib` file. I can't find any documentation on how to create the `.dll.a` file, or why my `.lib` file doesn't work. Looking for some guidance.

Commands used to create the `.dll` file from source:

```
cscript configure.js compiler=msvc prefix=c:\opt include=c:\opt\include lib=c:\opt\lib 
debug=yes iconv=no

nmake /f Makefile.msvc
```

Compile Errors:

> unresolved external symbol xmlNewDoc referenced in function
> unresolved external symbol xmlFreeDoc referenced in function

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was building as 32 bit for a 64 bit application. Once building on native x64 compiler development, it worked.